# How to import variables defined in __init__.py?

Tags: python

I'm a little confused about how importing works. Assume:

```
package/
    __init__.py
    file1.py
```

In `__init__.py`:

```
from file1 import AClass
__version__ = '1.0'
```

In `file1.py`:

```
Class AClass(object):
    def bar():
        # I want to use __version__here, but don't want to pass
        # it through the constructor. Is there any way?
        pass
```

If I use `from . import __version__` in `file1.py` it just says `ImportError: cannot import name __version__`.

Comment: might be wrong but __ means private ie can't be used elsewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
__version__ = '1.0'
from file1 import AClass
```

You need to assign the constants before you import the module so that it'll be in place when you try to import it.

*EDIT:* larsmans suggestion to avoid the circular dependency is a good idea.

Answer (score 7):

You've got a circular dependency because both files try to `import` each other. Move `__version__` to a separate module, say `package/version.py`, then import that in both others with

```
from .version import __version__
```